# XFDF - How to open XFDF file in Illustrator

Tags: pdf, adobe-illustrator, fdf, xfdf

How to open or view xfdf files in Illustrator. I know it can viewed in PDF but how to view it in Illustrator. Any advice or references is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XFDF files are data files for PDF forms, they cannot be viewed in Illustrator as there is nothing to see in them. They are XML files that contain field names and field values.
A XFDF file combined with the corresponding empty PDF form will give you a filled in PDF form.